# How to feed @ParameterizedTest based on config value

Tags: java, csv, junit, parameters, parameterized-tests

So I have created a parameterized test, which is a simple restassured test which logs into a user account.  I have some spring bean config in place, which you can specify a profile to pick up a certain test env, QA1, QA2, QA3 for example.  In each env I have different test accounts, I want to be able to run tests for QA1 for example it will run my ParameterizedTest for all the QA1 user accounts.  I'm hitting a block atm in that when I try to specify CSV source for my ParameterizedTest it requires a static variable for the filename, and my env config coming from the spring bean is not static.  Any ideas on how I might achieve this?  Some code...

```
@SpringBootTest
public class LoginLogoutTest {
    @Autowired
    ParamsConfig paramsConfig;
    String filename = paramsConfig.getUsersDataFile();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvFileSource(resources = filename, numLinesToSkip = 1)
    public void loginLogoutTest(String username, String password) {
//Some test stuff
}
}
```

I tried to specify via the bean config for CsvFileSource, but that requires static filepath.

I have tried to write a custom csv reader, but that also requires static filepath.

Comment: Thank you but no it doesn't.

Comment: you need to make sure that the file is readable in the Path from filename

Comment: Thanks but the loading of a CSV is fine for me, I am looking for a way in which to vary the csv file being read based upon spring or I guess any similar non-static config.